# Error while installing database engine service with SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server-2017

I get the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

while I am installing the SQL Server 2017 database engine service.

In previous tabs, only the windows firewall gives warning, but I already have made rule for port 1433. In SSMS, when I try to connect with database engine, it causes a login failed error (Error 18456, state:1).

I have already tried reinstalling and also tried to use .net framework repair tool, but that didn't help.

Also I found that interesting thing that I do not have problem with connecting to analyses services in SSMS.